# Integrating highcharts highstock in angular 4

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

Can somebody please suggest how to use highcharts-highstock in angular4? I have tried various configurations but, I have not been successful so far.

Comment: Any update on this question?

Comment: it works in angular 4 project as instructed here https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-highcharts#setting-up

Comment: I suggest you to use our official Highcharts wrapper, which has great documentation. Here is the link to npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-angular
There you can find the documentation. Please let me know about the result.